VulkanSDK Fetching the library with CMake
I am currently trying to link vulkan to my project in CMake. I want to download the VulkanSDK with CMake without depending anything but CMake.
I tried to use FetchContent but it only downloads the header files of VulkanSDK.
I tried to use ExternalProject but somehow it does the same thing as FetchContent.
I dont not even start implementing a script to download dxcompilerd, glslangd, shaderc_combinedd, spirv-cross-cored etc.
Test for ExternalProject
include(FetchContent)
include(ExternalProject)

set(VULKAN_VER_MAJOR 1)
set(VULKAN_VER_MINOR 3)
set(VULKAN_VER_PATCH 275)

set(VULKAN_VERSION ${VULKAN_VER_MAJOR}.${VULKAN_VER_MINOR}.${VULKAN_VER_PATCH})

ExternalProject_Add(
    vulkan
    PREFIX Vulkan
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers.git
    GIT_TAG v${VULKAN_VERSION}
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND ""
    INSTALL_COMMAND ""
    LOG_DOWNLOAD ON
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(vulkan SOURCE_DIR)
include_directories(${SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_library(Vulkan INTERFACE)
add_dependencies(Vulkan vulkan)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (VulkanTest "VulkanTest.cpp" "VulkanTest.h")

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest Vulkan)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET VulkanTest PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

Test for FetchContent
include(FetchContent)

set(VULKAN_VER_MAJOR 1)
set(VULKAN_VER_MINOR 3)
set(VULKAN_VER_PATCH 275)

set(VULKAN_VERSION ${VULKAN_VER_MAJOR}.${VULKAN_VER_MINOR}.${VULKAN_VER_PATCH})

FetchContent_Declare(
    vulkanheaders
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers.git
    GIT_TAG v${VULKAN_VERSION}
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_Declare(
    vulkanloader
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Loader.git
    GIT_TAG v${VULKAN_VERSION}
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_Declare(
    vulkanvalidation
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ValidationLayers.git
    GIT_TAG v${VULKAN_VERSION}
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

FetchContent_Declare(
    vulkantools
    GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Tools.git
    GIT_TAG v${VULKAN_VERSION}
    GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
    GIT_PROGRESS TRUE
)

set(PROJECT_IS_TOP_LEVEL OFF)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(vulkanheaders)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(vulkanloader)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(vulkanvalidation)
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(vulkantools)

add_library(myvulkan INTERFACE IMPORTED)
target_include_directories(myvulkan INTERFACE ${vulkan_headers_SOURCE_DIR}/include
    ${vulkan_loader_SOURCE_DIR}/loader
    ${vulkan_validation_layers_SOURCE_DIR}/layers
    ${vulkan_tools_SOURCE_DIR}/vulkaninfo)
target_link_libraries(myvulkan INTERFACE Vulkan::Vulkan)
target_link_libraries(myvulkan INTERFACE 
    Vulkan::Loader
    Vulkan::ValidationLayers
)

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (VulkanTest "VulkanTest.cpp" "VulkanTest.h")

target_link_libraries(VulkanTest PRIVATE myvulkan)

if (CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_GREATER 3.12)
  set_property(TARGET VulkanTest PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 20)
endif()

What should I do to make vulkan sdk ready for my project without depending on manually downloading it?

The Khronos official Vulkan samples repository already builds without requiring you to download the SDK.
It does this by including a bunch of other repositories as Git submodules but you could accomplish the same thing with FetchContent.
However, if you want a more detailed answer you're going to need to be more explicit about what's not working.

The issue in my system is that I cant link the lib/dll files to the header files of vulkan. I cant completely figure out what to add to my CMake script. I know that I need to fetch VulkanHeaders. but how do I handle lib files?

The header files are just the header files.  There's nothing to build or link against with them.  If you want something to link against you either need to download the actual SDK, or use a proxy loader like Volk (which is what the official Vulkan examples do).  The readme there has detailed instructions on how to use it.
